# print message on terminal as well as /var/log/messages using logger

Tags: bash, logger

I used below options in script to print on terminal as well as /var/log/messages

```
echo "System Load is OK : $Current_loadadv"
echo "System Load is OK : $Current_loadadv" | logger
```

but how can i do that in single line ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
tee >(logger) <<< "System Load is OK : $Current_loadadv"
```

`>(logger)` is bash syntax to create a file descriptor that is going to a FIFO, which is then fed to the standard input of `logger` (this is one form of what is known as "process substitution" in bash). It then passes back the path to that file descriptor as an argument to `tee`, and since `tee` writes to its non-option arguments, the FD is written to, and `logger` receives your string.

Comment: @RahulPatil: I don't know if that's actually the case, but as a mnemonic to remember tee, think of the letter `T`, it looks like a circuit splitter :)

Comment: @EmanuelBerg Yes, that's the origin of the name `tee`.

Answer (score 8):

Another Option :

```
logger -s "Message"
```

> man logger
>
> -s       Log the message to standard error, as well as the system log.